# \cite for website problem

Tags: bibtex, citing

[image][image]I am having difficulty with `\cite`,  would not compile some of the cites.  It is save in a file with extension `.bib` and the rest of the cites work fine but these ones do not. Any help?

```
@ONLINE{nistasd,
      title  = "",
      author = "",
      note   = "\url{https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html}",
      year   = ""
    } 

@MastersThesis{lopez,
    title    = {No wayout},
    school   = {Universidad de Pamplona},
    author   = {P. Lopez},
    year     = {2007}, 
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

%%%%%figure beyond 100
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
%\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
%\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.5em}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx,rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{amssymb}%checkmark on table
\usepackage{parskip}%paragraph separation
\setlength\parskip{5pt}%separation after title



\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\cfoot{\thepage}}}{\slshape \rightmark}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %lets the head rule disappear.
\lhead{\textbf{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{2.cm}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption,makecell}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[textfont=normalfont]{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\newcommand\apj{1925ApJ....61...38R}  % Journal abbreviations 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{.25in}  %topmargin control
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  %to include subsection in table of cont.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman}       %change page number style
\flushbottom


\begin{document}

This is given problem to compile  \cite{browning2008basic}
and this \cite{Siegman:98}.
and this \cite{lopez}  
and this \cite{nistasd}
and this \cite{doi:10.1063/1.2142102} 



\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{sourcespectra}

\end{document}
```

Here are some entries in the file `sourcespectra.bib`:

```
@book{browning2008basic,
  title={Basic Plasma Physics},
  author={Browning, B.},
  isbn={9781409219194},
  url={https://books.google.ie/books?id=pItUOwAACAAJ},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Lulu.com}
}


@inproceedings{Siegman:98,
author = {A. E. Siegman},
booktitle = {DPSS (Diode Pumped Solid State) Lasers: Applications and Issues},
journal = {DPSS (Diode Pumped Solid State) Lasers: Applications and Issues},
keywords = {},
pages = {MQ1},
publisher = {Optical Society of America},
title = {How to (Maybe) Measure Laser Beam Quality},
year = {1998},
url = {http://www.osapublishing.org/abstract.cfm?URI=DLAI-1998-MQ1},
doi = {10.1364/DLAI.1998.MQ1},
abstract = {},
}



@MastersThesis{lopez,
    title    = {No wayout},
    school   = {Universidad de Pamplona},
    author   = {P. Lopez},
    year     = {2007}, 
}

@ONLINE{nistasd,
      title  = "",
      author = "",
      note   = "\url{https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html}",
      year   = ""
    } 



@article{doi:10.1063/1.2142102,
author = {Shinsuke Fujioka and Hiroaki Nishimura and Katsunobu Nishihara and Masakatsu Murakami and Youngces-G Kang and Qincui Gu and Keiji Nagai and Takayoshi Norimatsu and Noriaki Miyanaga and Yasukazu Izawa and Kunioki Mima and Yoshinori Shimada and Atsushi Sunahara and Hiroyuki Furukawa},
title = {Properties of ion debris emitted from laser-produced mass-limited tin plasmas for extreme ultraviolet light source applications},
journal = {Applied Physics Letters},
volume = {87},
number = {24},
pages = {241503},
year = {2005},
doi = {10.1063/1.2142102},
URL = { http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2142102},
eprint = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2142102}
}





[![enter code here][2]][2]
```

Comment: Well, "does not compile" is not very helpful ... Please add the error message to your question!

Comment: This is the error given   Citation `nistasd' in file `chapter2/sourcespectra' on page 15 undefined and the same for the other one

Comment: Are you using the modern package biblatex? This stuff does not work with the old system by default.

Comment: where can i find it out? I am not quite sure.  I am using bib.tex

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? And, is there any reason for not setting the `author` field to `{NIST}` and the `title` field to `Atomic Spectra Database Levels Form`?

Comment: HI Mico, I tried but would not compile

Comment: I am using ieeetr

Comment: Please post a full minimal example. We need to know whether you are using `bibtex` or `biblatex`, the former rarely support the `@online` type, whereas the latter does.

Comment: The problem is that it is a phd thesis with files outside the main code.

Comment: Hi,I have added a simplified version and I hope this helps to deal with this problem because I do not know what to do.

Comment: After putting your bib entrys into a bib file I can compile your code without error or undefined citation ...  change type `online` to `misc`

Comment: It does not on my computer

Comment: I have posted the errors I am getting when compiling the document.

Comment: The screenshot of the error messages strongly suggests that you've failed to rerun BibTeX after adding a few `\cite` instructions. Please advise.

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of the error messages with the MWE you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your errors are only warnings and bad boxes.

Let us test another way.  Please copy the following MWE (I used package `filecontents` to have bib file and TeX code together in one MWE) to your computer. Call the file `mwe.tex`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{browning2008basic,
  title={Basic Plasma Physics},
  author={Browning, B.},
  isbn={9781409219194},
  url={https://books.google.ie/books?id=pItUOwAACAAJ},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Lulu.com},
}

@inproceedings{Siegman:98,
  author = {A. E. Siegman},
  booktitle = {DPSS (Diode Pumped Solid State) Lasers: Applications and Issues},
  journal = {DPSS (Diode Pumped Solid State) Lasers: Applications and Issues},
  keywords = {},
  pages = {MQ1},
  publisher = {Optical Society of America},
  title = {How to (Maybe) Measure Laser Beam Quality},
  year = {1998},
  url = {http://www.osapublishing.org/abstract.cfm?URI=DLAI-1998-MQ1},
  doi = {10.1364/DLAI.1998.MQ1},
  abstract = {},
}

@MastersThesis{lopez,
  title  = {No wayout},
  school = {Universidad de Pamplona},
  author = {P. Lopez},
  year   = {2007}, 
}

@misc{nistasd,
  title  = "",
  author = "",
  note   = "\url{https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html}",
  year   = ""
} 

@article{doi:10.1063/1.2142102,
  author = {Shinsuke Fujioka and Hiroaki Nishimura and Katsunobu Nishihara and Masakatsu Murakami and Youngces-G Kang and Qincui Gu and Keiji Nagai and Takayoshi Norimatsu and Noriaki Miyanaga and Yasukazu Izawa and Kunioki Mima and Yoshinori Shimada and Atsushi Sunahara and Hiroyuki Furukawa},
  title = {Properties of ion debris emitted from laser-produced mass-limited tin plasmas for extreme ultraviolet light source applications},
  journal = {Applied Physics Letters},
  volume = {87},
  number = {24},
  pages = {241503},
  year = {2005},
  doi = {10.1063/1.2142102},
  URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2142102},
  eprint = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2142102}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

%%%%%figure beyond 100
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
%\cftsetindents{figure}{0em}{3.5em}
%\cftsetindents{table}{0em}{3.5em}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{graphicx,rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{amssymb}%checkmark on table
\usepackage{parskip}%paragraph separation
\setlength\parskip{5pt}%separation after title

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\cfoot{\thepage}}}{\slshape \rightmark}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %lets the head rule disappear.
\lhead{\textbf{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{2.cm}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption,makecell}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[textfont=normalfont]{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\newcommand\apj{1925ApJ....61...38R}  % Journal abbreviations 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{.25in}  %topmargin control
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}  %to include subsection in table of cont.
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagenumbering{roman}       %change page number style
\flushbottom


\begin{document}

This is given problem to compile  \cite{browning2008basic}
and this \cite{Siegman:98}.
and this \cite{lopez}  
and this \cite{nistasd}
and this \cite{doi:10.1063/1.2142102} 

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}%\newpage\cleardoublepage
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Then use the compiling chain

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

Do not forget `bibtex mwe`!

Then you should get the following pdf without errors and warnings (one warning comes from package `filecontents`, that is okay):

[image]

Check the result on your computer with mine results. If your result is different, add command `\listfiles` before `\documentclass ...` and check the log file. At the end you will find a list of used packages and version numbers. Please compare it with the following list, resulting with an current MiKTeX 2.9:

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
rotating.sty    2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
multirow.sty    2016/11/25 v2.2 Span multiple rows of a table
 siunitx.sty    2017/08/02 v2.7j A comprehensive (SI) units package
   expl3.sty    2017/07/19 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2017/07/19 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2017/07/19 L3 Experimental document command parser
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
   array.sty    2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3keys2e.sty    2017/07/19 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
adjustbox.sty    2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-pdftex.def    2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for pdftex
ifoddpage.sty    2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
chapterbib.sty    2010/09/18  v 1.17
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
fancyhdr.sty    2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
 nccmath.sty    2005/02/21 v1.2 Additional Math Commands (NCC)
 amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11 `tabularx' package (DPC)
ragged2e.sty    2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
makecell.sty    2009/08/03 V0.1e Managing of Tab Column Heads and Cells
placeins.sty    2005/04/18  v 2.2
subcaption.sty    2016/05/22 v1.1-161 Sub-captions (AR)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2017/08/02 v2.7j siunitx: Abbreviated units
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
```

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of the error messages with the MWE you suggested. Kurt I am very new to Latex so everything you are suggesting here is very helpful for someone who know more than I.